# CSS animations without gradual and with instant change of properties

Tags: css

Using the `@keyframes` in CSS I can get animations where the properties are changed gradually over the `animation-duration`. But I want something to change the properties instantly. So that throughout 0% to 25% property of a tag would be one and then it would instantly change, not gradually. How do I do that?

Comment: you said it : *from 0% to 25% it should be one* then change you it at 26% for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.move-me {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.move-me-1 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4) infinite;
}
.move-me-2 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4, start) infinite;
}
.move-me-3 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s infinite;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes move-in-steps {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="move-me move-me-1">steps(4, end)</div>
<br>
<div class="move-me move-me-2">steps(4, start)</div>
<br>
<div class="move-me move-me-3">no steps</div>
```

what you need might be `steps()` in css animation
The code snippet I refer from this page
https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/

Comment: I needed to add `steps(1)` in the `animation` properties. That did the trick. Thanks